# Verify if a lat-long fall in my route

Tags: r, distance, intersection, latitude-longitude, ggmap

I am using ggmap package to generate routes. The resulting data frame will contain the routes information from the given source to the destination.

```
   library(ggmap)
    route_df <- route(from = "Cambridge, 02138, USA",
              to = "Massachusetts Ave, 02139, USA",
              mode = "driving", structure = "route", alternatives = TRUE)
```

I want to verify if a particular co-ordinate (-71.13857, 42.38039) fall in this route or not. 
I also want to verify if a coordinate (-71.13857, 42.38039) is part (one of the waypoints) of the route "A" resulted from the "route_df" variable. Is there any package that I can use to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the reproducible example below. You need to use Spatial objects.

```
# Load libraries
library('ggmap')
library('sp')
library('rgeos')
library('mapview') # Interactive maps in R

# Grab a route from Google
route_df <- route(from = "Cambridge, 02138, USA",
                  to = "Massachusetts Ave, 02139, USA",
                  mode = "driving", structure = "route", alternatives = TRUE)


# Find UTM projection
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186496/determining-utm-zone-to-convert-from-longitude-latitude
long2UTM <- function(long) {
  (floor((long + 180)/6) %% 60) + 1
}

long2UTM(route_df$lon)

# Convert route points to SpatialPointsDataFrame
routeSPDF <- route_df
coordinates(routeSPDF) <- c("lon", "lat")
proj4string(routeSPDF) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs") # original CRS
routeSPDF <- spTransform(x = routeSPDF, CRSobj = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=19 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")) # Transform (project)

# Convert routes to SpatialLinesDataFrame
possibleRoutes <- unique(routeSPDF$route)

# List of lines (one line is one possible route)
linesList <- list()

for(i in 1:length(possibleRoutes)) {
  linesList[[i]] <- Lines(slinelist = list(Line(coordinates(routeSPDF[which(routeSPDF$route == possibleRoutes[i]),]))), ID = possibleRoutes[i])
}

# SpatialLines
routesSL <- SpatialLines(LinesList = linesList, proj4string = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=19 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))

# Create particular coordinate as SpatialPoints object
point1 <- SpatialPoints(coords = cbind(-71.13857, 42.38039), proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
point1 <- spTransform(x = point1, CRSobj = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=19 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")) # Transform (project)

# Measure distance from points to lines (in meters)
gDistance(spgeom1 = point1, spgeom2 = routesSL, byid = TRUE)

# Verify if point1 fall in this route or not
gIntersects(spgeom1 = point1, spgeom2 = routesSL, byid = TRUE)
gWithinDistance(spgeom1 = point1, spgeom2 = routesSL, byid = TRUE, dist = 13.7)

# Verify if point1 is part (one of the waypoints) of the route "A" resulted from the "route_df"
gWithinDistance(spgeom1 = point1, spgeom2 = routesSL["A"], byid = TRUE, dist = 13.7)

# Test with a point from the line
testPoint <- routeSPDF[5,]
gDistance(spgeom1 = testPoint, spgeom2 = routesSL, byid = TRUE)
gWithinDistance(spgeom1 = testPoint, spgeom2 = routesSL, byid = TRUE, dist = 8.703543e-10)

# Plot
mapview(routeSPDF, zcol = 'route') + mapview(routesSL, zcol = 'ID') + mapview(point1, col = "black") + mapview(testPoint)
```

[image: map]

Comment: This is Excellent. Thank you for your reply Guzman.

I tried this code. I just have few questions.

When I test with point1  (-71.13857, 42.38039) according to the above code, it is not falling  in the route "A" .  However, it is within the distance (i.e, 13.7 meters cutoff) from the route. 

But if I try with a point that is already on the route, it shows the point does not intersects or does not fall in the route. Ex:- (-71.13731 , 42.37682)

Comment: @KarnaBhua =) I think it is a matter of resolution, or the number of digits an R user uses in R. If you check the *testPoint*, it's over the line because the distance is very small: almost zero ~8.703543e-10 m.

Comment: This is Excellent. Thank you for your reply Guzman.
I tried this code. I just have few questions.
1. When I test with point1  (-71.13857, 42.38039) according to the above code, it is not falling  in the route "A" .  But if I try with a point that is already on the route, it shows the point does not intersects or does not fall in the route. Ex:- (-71.13731 , 42.37682) This point is already on the route "A". 

2. mapview errors: 
Error in leaflet::colorNumeric(color, vals[[i]], na.color = na.color) : 
  Wasn't able to determine range of domain

Comment: Sorry, I have to re-edit. Please review my recent comment. Thanks Guzman. I have question on the error on mapview function and if I give a point form the path it should intersect right (meaning it should fall in the route)?

Comment: @KarnaBhua A1: I don't know what the error in *mapview* means, but try just to delete the *zcol* option. You can run only one map per time too: `mapview(routeSPDF, zcol = 'route')`. A2: yes, it should intersect. But I think it depends on the precisions of the digits you are using. Certainly I don't know why `gIntersect` give *FALSE* but `gDistance` gives a distance almost cero. if the distance is almost cero, certainly it intersects.

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes sense. I will also try mapview suggestion.